# Adding adjustable voltage capability to the output of a voltage tracker

Tags: operational-amplifier, dac

Using part: [TLS115D0LDXUMA1](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/196/Infineon-TLS115D0-DataSheet-v01_10-EN-1534863.pdf)

I need to drive a 120mA maximum load @10V.

The circuit must have the ability to adjust the voltage from Vref to 10V, where Vref=0-6V.

One goal is to bias Vref lightly: 100 uA max

So far I've come up with this, here is a rough sketch:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUDfvF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Any thoughts on which implementation to use in accomplishing this?

I was thinking about using an op-amp with Vout from the sketch tied to Vin+ of the op-amp in non-invert setup with the feedback portion tied to a DAC.  Example below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYLaFl.png)</sup>

Maximum load is 1.2W, which limits the usefulness of the op-amp setup as most devices would have trouble with that load at high temperature.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand the application (Because of my horrible understanding of English language). So you have a Vref voltage which varies between 0 and 6V. And you want to have an adjustable output voltage which varies between Vref to 10V. And the maximum current capability should be 120mA. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes Rohat, that is correct.  Also Vref should not be have a high load.

Comment: I am equally failing to understand your question. The part you mention drives the output to the same voltage as is applied on the adjust pin. So Vout = Vadj. Are you trying to build a circuit that maps the output of a DAC (e.g. 0-5V) to (Vref - 10V)?

Comment: Yes polwel that is correct.  I've come up with a new solution and will edit my question with the updates.